# Why are the outside walls of my house different shades?

Tags: the-sims-3

I'm really confused why my outside walls are two different shades. I used the exact same masonry/brick wall covering for both levels of the house, yet the upper level always appears darker than the lower level. It looks really odd. It can't just be shadows because the color difference is exact to where the levels change all the way around the house.

I had expanded the walls of the house from the original walls that came with it,so I thought it might be a case of the game thinking that they were indoor walls when they are actually outdoor walls, but I really have no idea. Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this weird shading issue? Is there any way to fix this and make the game use the correct shade of wall?

[image: The outside walls of my house during the day]

Notice in the picture that even the tile on the balcony to the right of the image is a darker shade than the normal (exact same) tile on the ground around the house. The game doesn't seem to like my second level.

[image: The outside walls of my house at night]

Notice that at night, the lower level walls adjust the shade of the wall to account for the time of day, but the upper level walls stay the exact same shade, as if the night doesn't affect them at all. At night, the upper level appears to be lighter (rather than darker) because of the shade difference.

Comment: It's a lighting issue. What is the time of day?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: I'm in the builder. One second, I'll take a picture of it in night time mode, the problem still persists.

Comment: Does the problem persist through save/load ?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Yes, it does.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with what level the currently active Sim is on?

Answer (score 1):

At looking at your pictures, i have an inkling that your walls are opposite when it comes to day and night.
I think its a slight glitch, somehow the second floor walls think its night when its actually day, and think its day when its actually night.

they are very simular, i think

if you disagree, then i guess it could be a contrast issue, or what raven said, a brightness issue, try colouring the wall yourself, play around with its brightness and contrast (if your able to)

hope any of this helps
Rob